# WooCommerce 2.1 Detect Chosen Shipping Method

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'd been using the following to decide if a checkout field needed to be complete or not...

```
if ($posted['shipping_method'] == "local_pickup_plus") {
}
```

Since updating to WooCommerce 2.1, my code no longer works.

I've tried to echo the value stored in $posted['shipping_method'] to see if I'm checking it against the correct value, but it appears nothing is stored in this variable anymore.

I've been looking for other methods of checking the chosen shipping method, but I'm not getting very far.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 22):

Been looking for this for a couple of hours, then decided to delve into the WooCommerce files...

This seems to be working for me:

```
 $chosen_methods = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );
 $chosen_shipping = $chosen_methods[0];
```

I'm using this to set a min total for local delivery by using it like this in my functions.php

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','woocommerce_custom_surcharge' );
function woocommerce_custom_surcharge() {
global $woocommerce;


if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
return;

 $chosen_methods = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );
 $chosen_shipping = $chosen_methods[0]; 

 $min_spend = 25;
 $cart_total = $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total;
 if (($cart_total < 25) AND ($chosen_shipping == 'local_delivery')) {   
    $surcharge = $min_spend-$cart_total;    
    $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( 'Delivery Surchage', $surcharge, true, 'standard' );
}

}
```

Hope this helps someone out.

Comment: Still working. Thank you!

Comment: This works somehwhat but a few things: You don't use to use global $woocommerce when you can get the same info from `WC()` see here: https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-get-cart-info-total-items-etc-from-cart-object/

Also, the value returned by "chosen_shipping_methods" is not an exact match, but it does contain the shipping method name, so you'd have to do `strpos` and NOT `===`

Answer (score 0):

From the [source code](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/class-wc-checkout.php) of the WooCommerce 2.1 :

`$this->posted['shipping_method'] = isset( $_POST['shipping_method'] ) ? $_POST['shipping_method'] : '';`

So if the variable `$_POST['shipping_method']` is not set, then `$posted['shipping_method']` will be empty string. My guess is that your `form` does not have the `method` attribute set to `post` (it is omitted maybe or you try to use links for product submission, not the `form`).

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
The forms method attribute is set to post.
The form in question is the WooCommerce Checkout.

Comment: I've been trying '$test = $posted['shipping_method'];
 $woocommerce->add_error( __('Selected shipping method is' . $test) );' and the error message area just has "Selected shipping method is" printed in it.

Comment: I'm now starting to think it's the priority in which the code is being added...
'add_action('woocommerce_after_checkout_validation', 'validate_collection_date', 20, 1);' so will need to look into this further.

Comment: If you find a bug in WooCommerce, better to post it on issue tracker there, so the developers will be able to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

$_POST['shipping_method'] is an array, $whatever = $_POST['shipping_method'], $whatever[0] = value